# compiler isn't recognizing a value in a struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to solve this problem uselessly for a long time... I'll be glad for help.

I have this *enum* defined:

```
enum state { empty, black , white , possible};
```

and these 2 structs:

```
typedef struct s_node
{
    struct s_node* next;
    struct s_node* prev;
    state color;
    int place; //0...63
} ListNode;
```

and:

```
typedef struct b_node
{
    state color;
    ListNode* ptr;
} ArrNode;
```

and finally class Board:

```
class Board
{
private:
    state turn;
    ArrNode board[SIZE][SIZE];
    ListNode *head, *tail, *list, *black_end, *white_end;
    Possible *possHead;
    int black_num, white_num;
    friend class Play;
public:
        Board(){...}
        ...
};
```

I initialize the ListNode with color=empty, and so the ArrNode board.
But when i run the code and about to go through the ListNode I get this:
[image]

and when i click the green refresh button i get this:
[image]

*edit:
here i=19 but i showed `board[3][3]` (i=27)...
here's a correct snapshot:
[image]*

But when i step over (F10) it doesn't enter the if condition.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

*edit:*
Here's how i initialize ArrNode board[SIZE][SIZE]:

```
head = new ListNode;
list = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                board[i][j].color = empty;
                list->next = new ListNode;
                list->next->prev = list;
                list = list->next;
                list->color = empty;
                board[i][j].ptr = list;
                list->place = i*SIZE + j;
            }
        list->next = NULL;
```

Comment: First, you may want to make sure ArrNode is properly initialized, because as it is now all your getting is default-initialization. If you want `Board` to value-initialize all the members in that 2D array you should add `board()` to the `Board::Board()` constructor initializer list. Second, `*board + i` is effectively `board[0] + i` *always*. Is that your intent, to always drive through the first "row" of your 2D array? If that is the case, when why isn't `board` simply `board[SIZE*SIZE]` and just use `board + i` ?

Comment: How do you initialize this ArrNode board[SIZE][SIZE];?

Comment: Unrelated: I just noticed the `next` value in your last screenshot for `Possible *temp`, which is `0xCDCDCDCD`. That isn't good, as it generally means your not initialing your structure pointers either. *All* of those should be taken care of at construction and management of the respective objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig i don't understand what you mean by adding `board()` to `Board::Board()`. And `board[0]+i` isn't always the first row... as you can see i=19.

Comment: @Nik i posted it. Have a look

Comment: @AlaaM. I realize that. Thus my question, was it your intention to drive to all your *other* rows via dereference **through** the *first* row? And regarding adding `board` to the initializer list, I mean `Board::Board() : board() {...}` as well as all the other member variables that should be initialized (not just in `Board`, but in *all* your structs and classes).

Comment: @WhozCraig OK i changed the board definition to `board[SIZE*SIZE]`, changed the way to access the board cells to: `board[i]`, and added constructors to my structs (didn't know that thing exists) and maybe some other little corrections and then it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AlaaM. No problem. Always *know* what you're starting with before trying to go somewhere with it. Indeterminate values are one of the top-reasons for undefined behavior in C/C++, and it is thankfully one of the easiest to correct. Try and make it a practice. Glad its working ok for you now.